# Highlighted Content Strange Results

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages, highlighted-content-web-part

When setting up a Highlighted Content part on a modern page, sometimes my query will output the following 4 rows (1 x "Automatically show content from your site", with 3 x "Title"):

[image]

These do not reflect my content in any way, and almost seem like placeholder content to indicate that my query has errors.

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help me understand this odd behavior.

Comment: It is the default view of the web part. If no content is found, it shows these results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a default behavior of Highlighted Content web part If there is nothing to show in the web part (i.e. If query does not returns any result).

Also, there is one option to hide the web part if there is nothing to show like given below:

[image]

You can check this checkbox to hide the web part if there is nothing to show.

You can read more about Highlighted Content web part in below article:

[Use the Highlighted content web part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-highlighted-content-web-part-e34199b0-ff1a-47fb-8f4d-dbcaed329efd).